# Quartz 2D substitude for graphicsPort in SDK 10.10

Tags: deprecated, cgcontext, quartz-2d

## The scenario:

I'm editing some `CGImage`s and strangely enough until now I was first creating `NSImage`s from those `CGImage`s before drawing them. So I tried to change the code so that I would draw the `CGImage`s directly in into `NSGraphicsContext.currentContext().graphicsPort`. As you see I'm using Swift here but the same problem goes for Objective-C I presume.

Having a look into the documentation I saw that `graphicsPort` will be deprecated in 10.10, but I couldn't find another way to the current `CGContext` from `NSGraphicsContext` nor is there a way to create the `CGContext` from an `NSGraphicsContext`.

## The Question:

Does anybody know what the proper way to retrieve the context would be? If not - Is there a way to cast the `graphicsPort`'s `COpaquePointer`, which apparently is an initialized `NSPipe`Object, to a `CGContextRef`? Although using code that has already been marked deprecated would be quite unsatisfactory I would consider it until there is a better solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After spending a half hour digging around for information on this, I realized I should just check out the header file for `NSGraphicsContext`. Turns out there's a new property on `NSGraphicsContext` that's apparently not documented yet: `CGContext`. The header also notes that this should be used instead of `graphicsPort`.

Comment: Well, after updating to the current beta version there was indeed this member in the header. But I guess there's a reason why it is not documented yet, since trying to use it throws an 'unrecognized selector' error.

Using ```let contextPointer = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()!.graphicsPort
let context = UnsafePointer<CGContext>(contextPointer).memory```
would result in an 'invalid context'. So for now I'm back to using NSImages for drawing into my view again.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the comment, but isn't `let context = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()?.CGContext` what you want?